# KVM Setting Issue (libvirt-sock not found) on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I have been following this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation to install KVM on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. But I cannot start it properly and encounter the following errors.

```
$ virsh list --all
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': 
       No such file or directory
```

The directory `/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock` indeed does not contain `libvirt-sock`

```
$ ls /var/run/libvirt
network  storage  virtlockd-sock  virtlogd-sock
```

What are the solutions to this issue? and how can I install KVM properly? 
Many Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sockets are a special type of file that should get created when the libvirt daemon starts.
My guess is, libvirtd is not running - to start it, try:

```
systemctl start libvirtd
```

To check it's status, try:

```
systemctl status libvirtd
```

It may also not be enabled, therefore would not run by default on reboot - you can fix this with:

```
systemctl enable libvirtd
```

Comment: Thanks. Checking the status `systemctl status libvirtd` gives three errors.  1. `Failed to parse user 'libvirt-qemu'` 2. `Initialization of QEMU state driver failed` 3. `Driver state initialization failed`.  The errors are still here even after `enable`

Comment: Ok, so there's a bit of info on your error in this bug report: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=768000 - the washup, make sure the `libvirt-daemon-system` pkg is installed. It *should* have installed automatically, but it is not explicitly a dependency (just a recommends). You can check that with `apt depends virt-manager`

Comment: I have `libvirt-daemon-system` installed. But still don't know what is the issue

Comment: I guess at this point you're just going to need to create the user yourself, and apply membership appropriately. It's covered in this post in the bug I linked earlier: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=768000#10

Comment: I tried to follow the link to create users and add groups, but the errors are still here.

Comment: Did you try to start the libvirtd service again?

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, I needed to install libvirt-daemon-kvm (on Fedora 33) after virt-manager quit connecting on me. Thanks for the help.